# Are root finding algorithms stable for bounded polynomials?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, rootfinding

Suppose that we have a bounded polynomial defined on $[0,1]$. I think because it is just polynomial, root finding algorithms would easily and without any instability find all its roots. Am I right?
And what is the fastest and most stable root-finding algorithm for my problem?

Edit: I introduce my polynomial as:
$$ f(x) = B_n(x) - x$$

$B_n(x)$ is a bernstein polynomial with positive and strictly increasing coefficients $a_k$:

$$B_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom n ka_kx^k (1-x)^{n-k}$$

$$a_0=0 < a_1 < a_2 < ... < a_n=1$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by bounded polynomial?

Comment: Are the coefficients integer, or real, or complex, or something else entirely… and do you want real roots, or complex roots etc?

Comment: Any polynomial can be transformed to a polynomial with all its real roots in $[0,1]$ and its absolute value there less than 1. So these restrictions don't change the difficulty of root finding.

Comment: The coefficients are bounded and real. I only need real roots. It is bounded on $[0,1]$. For more information it has just one roots in $[0,1]$.

Comment: The Sturm  Theorem and Sturm sequences seem to do the job for you (for real roots of real polynomials).

Comment: If you know that the polynomial changes sign between 0 and 1, bisection will give the root fast enough in practice and it is very accurate. At the risk of non-convergence, Newton's method will be faster but it won't give you rigorous bounds.

Comment: I only need a convergent method which could estimate the root faster than any methods and under any circumstances. Estimated root must be at most 1e-6 away from actual root. I use a numerical library. I don't want any instability.  Which particular method should I should?

Comment: Use a few iterations of Newton's method. Then check that the polynomial changes sign in the interval of size 1e-6 surrounding the point you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding **real** roots is not going to be stable, even if you assume the polynomial to be monic and have bounds on where the interesting stuff happens. As an example, consider $(x^2 + \varepsilon)(x^2 - 2x + 1 - \varepsilon)$. If $\varepsilon < 0$, the only real root is at $0$, if $\varepsilon > 0$ the only real root is at $1$.

If you want a guarantee that the algorithm will converge to a root with bounds on the convergence speed, you'd need to either promise the existence of roots with odd multiplicty, or be willing to accept complex roots as solutions.

Comment: I already said that the polynomial has exactly one root.

Comment: @bitWise Please edit all relevant information into the question. If you know that there is a unique root, you can find it effectively. However, if you have a "good reason" for why there is a unique root it will be much easier to give a reasonable algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand what to do.